# How can I create an FFT graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft

I have data for the y axis of a graph and I need to perform an FFT on the data and plot it. I don't have much experience with MATLAB, so any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html

http://www.ele.uri.edu/~hansenj/projects/ele436/fft.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll research into the matter.

Comment: The matlab example above is great because: it shows how to make the x-axis vector for frequency to plot against the spectrum data, takes in to account plotting the magnitude of the data, cuts off the complex conjugates so you don't get a mirrored image, and will calculate the next power of 2 to use to make the calculation more efficient.

It might also be helpful to check out pwelch for a power spectral density